# Flutter infinite width exception

Tags: flutter

I want to align my transaction title and date to the left but when I give the parent container the full width of the row i.e. double.infinity, the following exception is thrown "BoxConstraints forces an infinite width". What could be the possible reason?

```
body: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          new Card(child: new Text("CHART!")),
          new Column(
            children: [
              ...transactions.map((transaction) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new Row(
                    children: [
                      new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10,
                          horizontal: 15,
                        ),
                        child: new Text(
                          transaction.amount.toString(),
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.purple),
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Column(
                        children: [
                          new Container(
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: new Text(
                              transaction.title,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            child: new Text(
                              transaction.date.toString(),
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              })
            ],);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Row()` widget does not have a width property, meaning that you should put the `Row()` inside another `Container()`, so that the row knows what its constraints are, like this:

```dart
                  new Row(
                    children: [
                      new Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.purple,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          vertical: 10,
                          horizontal: 15,
                        ),
                        child: new Text(
                          transaction.amount.toString(),
                          style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.purple),
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Column(
                        children: [
                          new Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,,
                            child: new Text(
                              transaction.title,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            child: new Text(
                              transaction.date.toString(),
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
```

Note: the `new` keyword is optional. Furthermore, setting a width to infinity will only cause problems, since it will always go out of the screen, creating an overflow.

Comment: The only change needed is from `double.infinity` to `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`, something that returns the width of the display.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `You are setting stretch for crossAxisAlignment`, which gives infinite width to the column. You can provide constraint to the Container, through width property by setting

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

This should work.